My react application is setting the className on the wrong elements
My application is a calendar. It is highlighting the wrong day.
I want it to highlight today, but, it is highlighting the day after today.  And for other months, it is highlighting the same day of the month.
It works just fine when I run the app using VSCode.  The problem only appears when I deploy the app on Vercel.
The way I highlight days is by applying a className.  If the day is today, I apply an additional className of 'today'.  If the day is not today, the className is simply 'day'
Here is the code.  The week is an array of days.  Each day is a moment (i.e. moment.js).
I have logging that shows that isToday is true for the correct day.
Some more background.  I had this problem a while ago.  It seemed to possibly be related to hydration errors.  If I recall correctly the problem went away when I disabled server rendering?
Anyway, it's back, so I need to find out what's going on.
export default function Week({ week, today, index }) {

    let days = [];
    let dayOfWeek = 1;
    for (const day of week) {
        let isToday = day.date() === today.date() && day.month() === today.month() && day.year() === today.year();
        if (isToday) {
            console.log(`This day is today: ${day}`);
            days.push(<div className='today day' day={day} index={dayOfWeek} key={dayOfWeek}>{day.format('MMM D')}</div>);
        } else {
            days.push(<div className='day' day={day} index={dayOfWeek} key={dayOfWeek}>{day.format('MMM D')}</div>);
        }
        dayOfWeek++;
    }
    return <div className='week'>
        {days.map((day) => (
            day
        ))}
    </div>
}

I have this in my styles.css file
.today {
    background-color: aqua;
}

I tried only including today.  When I go through all the days of the month that is to be displayed, if the day is today, I add it to the calendar.  If the day is not today, then I don't add it.  So if we are displaying the current month, it will only have today.  If we are displaying any other month, it will have no days.  This is a test to see if I am applying the className to the correct element.  This test seems to work.  The current month has only the one day for today.  And all other days are empty.

Can you setup a stackblitz project with the minimal working sample?
